# ASP-VB Script encoding problem - Microsoft SQL server is not returning error message in page encoding format

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8, vbscript

I have a ASP/VBScript page. I have set the encoding to UTF-8 using the following:

```
<%@ CodePage=65001 %>
```

The existing `Response.write()` messages are coming in UTF-8. But when I add a new `Response.write()` message, IE shows it in Shift JIS encoding. The System Locale setting is Japanese.

New code added:

```
if err.number <> 0 then
 Response.write <Japanese error message>
 Response.end
end if
```

Why are the existing `Response.write()` shown in UTF-8 and only new one shown in Shift JIS?

To get over this, I added below line at top of page:

```
Response.Charset="UTF-8"
```

On adding this, the new `Response.write()` started coming in UTF-8. But MS SQL Server error messages (like timeout) also were displayed in UTF-8. They are appearing as junk characters. They are shown correctly only in Shift JIS as MS SQL Server is encoding them as Shift JIS.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to show more of your code, and of the result it produces. You also need to double-check which file encoding you are using for your `.asp` source files (use a good text editor to check that, i.e. not Notepad).

Comment: Included the newly added code in question. Also I am using Notepad++ for editing which correctly saves the file as UTF-8 encoded. This is confirmed since the error message is displayed correctly in UTF-8 in IE.

Comment: I assume the error message text is saved in the ASP file itself? Also: You did not show the code that does _not_ work, and you did not show the resulting page. You can paste Japanese characters here, please provide the exact details that are necessary to reproduce the issue. This guessing game is tiresome.